# interactive marker - processFeedback()

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to have an interactive marker as part of a class that I'm making, but am running into trouble with the `processFeedback()` as a member function.

I can define it as `static void processFeedback()` which works but then I need to pass an instance to the function (which I can't seem to figure out how to do).

When I don't make the function `static` I get a bunch of boost errors and `no match for call to ....` error.

How do I either pass the static function an instance or how do I define the function so that I don't have to use `static`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259196/interactive-marker---processfeedback()/) by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guess I should learn boost... although I only found this in a random post. Not sure what's really going on.

`menu_handler.insert("menu item", boost::bind(&MyClass::processFeedback, this, _1));`

---

Originally posted by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) with karma: 235 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1